# Duda con Login en NodeJS con MongoDB

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, login, jwt

## Tengo las siguientes dudas:

1. De que forma esta bien hacerlo(las dos me funcionan por igual)?

```js
// De esta:
router.post("/login", function (req, res) { 
    Usuario.findOne({ username: req.body.username }, (err, user) => {
        if(!user) ...
}); 
}); 
// O está:
router.post("/login", async function (req, res) { 
    const user = await Usuario.findOne({ username: req.body.username }); 
    if(!user) ... 
});
```

2. Porque se devuelven los datos del usuario en el login, no se deberia responder solo con el token, y al necesitar los datos del usuario hacer una peticion get utilizando el token?

```js
// Porque esto
router.post("/login", function (req, res) { 
...
return res.json({
        token,
        user: {
          _id,
          name,
          email,
          role
        }
});
// y no esto?
router.post("/login", function (req, res) { 
...
return res.json({
        token
});
// O de esta otra forma que he visto en otro lado:
return res.header('auth-token', token).json({
        error: null,
        data: { token },
        message: 'Bienvenido'
    })
```

Comment: Yo creo que la pregunta esta sujeta a opiniones... yo por ejemplo en la pregunta 1 prefiero usar el `async/await`. La segunda, cualquiera es valida, quizas lo hacen para que desde el login no sea necesario un llamado extra al servidor para traer sus datos... es muy probable que si devuelves el token, sea casi obligatorio llamar enseguida al endpoint para obtener los datos del usuario con ese token, quizas lo hacen para evitar ese llamado extra.

Comment: @Pipe Entiendo gracias amigo, una consulta en el token puden ir el id y el rol, para que al decodificar el token comprobar si es admin?

Comment: normalmente cuando hablamos de token, hablamos de JWT (JSON Web token) y efectivamente normalmente se incluye el rol y el identificador unico del usuario